# How to do 3 nested group by in linq

Tags: linq

I found this example of nested group by in linq. How would it look if I want to add one more `group by` to it?

```
  var queryNestedGroups =
        from student in students
        group student by student.Year into newGroup1
        from newGroup2 in
            (from student in newGroup1
             group student by student.LastName)
        group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let rename some variables of the sample query:

```
var queryNestedGroups =
    from e in source
    group e by e.Key1 into g1
    from e1 in
        (from e in g1
         group e by e.Key2)
    group e1 by g1.Key;
```

Now you can add another nested group level using the same pattern:

```
var queryNestedGroups =
    from e in source
    group e by e.Key1 into g1
    from e1 in
        (from e in g1
         group e by e.Key2 into g2
         from e2 in 
            (from e in g2
             group e by e.Key3)
         group e2 by g2.Key)
    group e1 by g1.Key;
```